Why doesn't ansible pick SSH_AUTH_SOCK to use the agent when ssh'ing with keys
As part of running a playbook I'm setting up an agent and add a key to it:
- name: Start ssh agent
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - common_vars.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Start the SSH agent
      shell: |
        ssh-agent -s
      register: ssh_agent_result

    - name: Extract the SSH Agent PID
      set_fact:
        ssh_agent_socket: "{{ ssh_agent_result.stdout | regex_search('(/tmp/ssh-[^;]+/agent.[0-9]+)') }}"

    - name: Add the SSH private key to the agent (using the SSH Agent PID)
      shell: ssh-add /home/max/projects/kw-infra-simplified/terraform/do-compose-private-instance-key.pem
      environment:
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK: "{{ ssh_agent_socket }}"

And then I use this SSH_AUTH_SOCK in the next play:
- name: Ping instances
  hosts: apps
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    ssh_agent_pid: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ssh_agent_pid }}"
    ssh_agent_socket: "{{ hostvars['localhost'].ssh_agent_socket }}"
    ansible_ssh_user: ubuntu
  environment:
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: "{{ ssh_agent_socket }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Debug the extracted SSH Agent PID
      debug:
        msg: "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is {{ ssh_agent_socket }}"

    - name: Ping the apps instances
      ping:

Which works just fine and outputs the debug message "SSH_AUTH_SOCK is {{ ssh_agent_socket }}" with the correct path to the ssh-agent socket. However, it can't connect to the remote host and when inspecting the output from the ssh:
ansible-playbook -vvvvv ping.yaml

I can see that the ssh doesn't attempt to use the agent. What could be the reason for this? Is what I'm trying to do is even possible?

What about inventory file? You need to set the path of the SSH private key in the inventory file.

yeah, I can do that in many places, but the idea is to not use the path to the key, but instead use ssh agent
